# Turn off tracking in entity framework model first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm tring to receive an entity and then update it, but I want to get it with no tracking, so I can attach it back to the context.

I have the `EntityFramework.dll` referenced (4.1). I generated the database from the model. (not code-first).

Get user:

```
db.Users.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
IQueryable<User> query = db.Users;//.AsNoTracking(); //<-- apparently, this is code-first only.

return query;
```

Update user:

```
db.Users.Attach(user); //error here.
ObjectStateEntry entry = db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user);
entry.SetModifiedProperty(propertyName);
db.SaveChanges();
return user;
```

Error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I call the method like this:

```
var user = userRepository.GetUsers().FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
user.Identifiers.Add(someIdent);
userRepository.UpdateUser(user);
```

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that you are not receiving user with another query?

Comment: @Ladislav same query. I only have 1 read/get method in the repository, which uses that code

Comment: I just tested similar code without all repository burden and it works for me.

Comment: @Ladislav, would the way how I instanciate the context cause this problem? I use ninject as follows: `kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToMethod(context => new MyDbContext(theconnString)).InRequestScope();`

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem but I don't understand why are you using `NoTracking` if you are going to attach it again back to the same context and save it. `NoTracking` is for scenarios where you don't want to change the entity.

Comment: @Ladislav, because I may create an entity with code from just the Id, just to update specific properties (without asking for the data from the server then sending it back)

Comment: That has nothing to do with tracking. In you scenario tracking is not needed because it will simply work. In the scenario where you need to create the entity in code you will simply check if it is attached and if not you will attach it and set modified properties.

Comment: @Ladislav, I tried what you said and now It tells me `The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type ` when running the code: `db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user);`

Comment: what is Identifiers in `user.Identifiers.Add(someIdent);` is that an entity as well? If so, could that be the one causing the "same key already exists"-error?

Answer (score 19):

No-tracking Queries
Sometimes you may want to query for entities but not have the entities be tracked by the context. This may result in better performance when querying for large numbers of entities in read-only scenarios. The AsNoTracking extension method executes a query and returns the results without tracking them in the context. In the following example, the queries will return objects but they will not be tracked by the context.
other

```
       // Query for all departments without tracking them
       var departments1 = context.Departments.AsNoTracking().ToList();

      // Query for some departments without tracking them
      var departments2 = context.Departments
                .Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("math"))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of detaching and attaching. If you want to handle Updating an item that may or may not be from the original context, you could do the following.

```
var originalItem = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
db.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when my object (originalItem) has a property which is a collection of child entities. Is there something special I need to do for this case?